# Caml query after modified choices

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, query

I have a column with an internal name of: PublicY with 2 choices: Yes/No, the query works but if I change the choice name to Ja/Nej the code will not query the results, why? I have tried to change the code to Ja/Nej also

```
        <Eq>";
        <FieldRef Name='PublicY' />";                           
        <Value Type='Choice'>YES</Value>";
        </Eq>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a choice field with two values "Ja" and "Nej", the query

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='PublicY' />                           
    <Value Type='Choice'>Ja</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

should work. Or you can use a boolean field instead, then there's a checkbox in user interface, and the query would be

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='PublicY' />                           
    <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: I have tryied with your first option its not working, i have removed all the content type and built it again and its not working

Comment: @Gintas is right in his 2nd option. Use boolean(Yes/No) instead of choice.